# Seemingly incorrect user is shown to have last modified post

Tags: bug

On the front page, it showed a particular user was the last one to modify part of a question:

> [image]

But when I looked at the edit history, that user wasn’t there, and they hadn’t supplied an answer:

> [image]

What’s going on? Did they provide an answer and then delete it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this "answer" was deleted by the moderators, as it didn't answer the question but repeated parts of the question.

If you have enough [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) (10.000 to access the moderators tools), you can see these deleted answers.